# Is const in copy ctor redundant in a class which already had move ctor?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a class with both copy ctor and move ctor being defined, do I need to make the copy ctor's parameter `const`?

Comment: yes ...comment padding...

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: why would you make it mutable? What does move ctor have to do with the  const-ness of the cpy ctor parameter? Does your copy ctor modifies the object it copies? No. So then you make it `const T&`.

Comment: also follow the principle of least astonishment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#cctor-constructors-assignments-and-destructors That's how a copy ctor should de defined like. Define it as such. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c22-make-default-operations-consistent

Answer (score 1):

If the copy ctor does not take a const reference parameter but a reference parameter, then you will not be able to copy construct const objects. Having a move ctor does not help because the move ctor moves the passed object, whereas in the copy ctor you want to copy it.

And as bolov said: if you do not modify the passed object, then make it const reference. This rule applies to all functions, not only to copy ctor.

Comment: to make clear for everyone: we are talking about passing by reference. If you pass by value, const doesn't matter.